# Unable to load a GWT app on browser

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

I tried the suggested answer given on various stackoverflow question but I am having this error still. I tried to remove the gwt cahce by removing .Intellijidea/system/gwt/*

Browser: chrome,firefox

OS: Centos 6.5

IDE: IntellijIdea

```
[ERROR] Failure in unit cache map load.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read from byte cache
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.awaitUnitCacheMapLoad(PersistentUnitCache.java:466)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.find(PersistentUnitCache.java:391)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.addArchive(CompilationStateBuilder.java:365)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.ArchivePreloader.preloadArchives(ArchivePreloader.java:65)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase$UiBrowserWidgetHostImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:106)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:197)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read from byte cache
        at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferFromStream(DiskCache.java:171)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken.readObject(DiskCacheToken.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:771)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.readObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:205)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.loadUnitMap(PersistentUnitCache.java:517)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.access$800(PersistentUnitCache.java:96)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$4.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected EOF in middle of data block
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(ObjectInputStream.java:2539)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2702)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:865)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferFromStream(DiskCache.java:159)
        ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by corrupted gwt cache. Delete the content of `gwt-unitCache` folder and run your application.